# Enviar parametro por ajax y confirmar eliminación

Tags: mysql, ajax, sweetalert

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual me muestra un swal para confirmar la eliminación de un registro si bien me aparece la alerta al momento de aceptar no me elimina el registro este es el codigo. En el recibirEliminarUsuario.php recibo el rut y procedo a eliminar el usuario.Saludos

```
function mensajeEliminar(){

        var url="consultas/recibirEliminarUsuario.php"
        var user= document.getElementById("rut").value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data:{rut:user},
            success: function(datos){

               if(datos){
                swal({
          title: "¿Estás seguro de eliminar este usuario?",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {

            swal("Los datos han sido eliminados exitosamente", {
                icon: "success",
            });
            }
        });
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el código no está bien planteado. Si lo que quieres es un dialogo de confirmación antes de enviar la petición de eliminar el usuario, me parece que deberías estructurarlo algo así:

```
function mensajeEliminar() {
    swal({
        title: "¿Estás seguro de eliminar este usuario?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete.value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {rut: user},
                success: function(datos) {
                    swal("Los datos han sido eliminados exitosamente", {
                      icon: "success",
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la información de todas formas lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera

Comment: Deseo hacer lo mismo un swal de confirmación para luego enviar los datos serializados pero no me me funciona haciéndolo como hice el para eliminar

Answer (score 0):

```
 function mensajeEliminar(){
        var url="../../php/recibirEliminarUsuario.php"
        var user= document.getElementById("rut").value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data:{rut:user},
            success: function(datos){
              swal({
          title: "¿Estás seguro de eliminar este usuario?",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        }).then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {

            swal("Los datos han sido eliminados exitosamente", {
                icon: "success",
            });
            document.getElementById("rut").value="";
            document.getElementById("rut2").value="";
            document.getElementById("tipo_usuario").value="";
            document.getElementById("email").value="";
            document.getElementById("nombre").value="";
            document.getElementById("apellidos").value="";
            document.getElementById("genero").value="";
            document.getElementById("anexo").value="";
            document.getElementById("area").value="";
            }
        });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function enviarDatosModificar(){
        var url="../php/recibirModificar.php"
        var dataString = $('#formModi').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data:dataString,
            success: function(datos){

            }
        });
    }
```

Alguna idea de como podria hacer un swal de confirmación con esta función